# In a react/redux application where is the right place to make api call to persist updated state to backend server?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So my reducer is creating and returning a new state. Where is the right place to make an api call to persist this data to the backend server?

Comment: do you want the ui (reducer) will get updated with new state regardless of the back-end success for saving the new data?

Comment: I suppose not, no an error should be displayed instead. So maybe the backend persist needs to be called before I hit the reducer. So i'm confused where to do what. I need to update state, try to persist and if sucuss all ok, otherwise show error and revert to previous state

Comment: If you want to update the ui after the server successfully saved data, then in the action (thunk if your using `redux-thunk`) you will trigger the ajax call and on success disptach the action creator

Comment: So i'm thinking, my action will create some new objects, try to persist them to server, on success dispatch another action to update state with new object, or on failure dispatch another action to report error.

Comment: Yeah, this is what i would do. There is another approach called optimistic updates where you update the ui no matter what, then calling the server then if needed (error from server) updating the ui again. there is a nice [enhancer for reducer with this approach](https://github.com/mattkrick/redux-optimistic-ui)

Comment: If we talking about where to put the majority of your business logic, the answer is always **Server**. If we talking about middlewares needed, I would suggest `axios` (for your ajax calls), and `redux-thunk` (for making your `async` requirements more pleasant). Depending on the level of your error handling, for simple cases use basic `HTML5` validation, if you need a more complex structure, again, put it all on the server-side. And when it comes to React life-cycles, make your async calls in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main approaches to sync UI updates and Server updates:

#### Server First *(not an official name)*

Where you first dispatching an async action to the server, then when resolved you update the UI, in your case dispatching an action creator with a `success` or an `error`.

#### Optimistic Updates

You update the UI no matter what, then calling the server. If there is an error you update the UI again.
There is a nice reducer enhance library [redux-optimistic-ui](https://github.com/mattkrick/redux-optimistic-ui) that helps with this approach.

Comment: yes the server first approach would be called "pessimistic updates". I was going to attempt to implement pessimistic updates. Are you suggesting an optimistic approach is better (or easier to implement)?

Comment: In my opinion its not a matter of better or easier, its a matter of preference and what fit your use case best. I mostly do server first. Optimistic updates may feel faster to the user, but i think when you do have errors and needs to rollback or revert data then it may be confusing.

Comment: I'm struggling to find examples of how to do this. Currently my action creators figure out what needs to be done and dispatch the correct actions. My reducers listen to the actions and update state. I don't see how to save the changes after the reducers have made the changes. I tried switching my approach to get the action creators to create the changes, but this requires the action creators to access the store which seems incorrect. There are lots of examples of how to pull data from a server and display it, but not many that show how to save changes back to the server.

Comment: Did you check the library i posted?